# PayPal Express Checkout - error 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, braintree

I am trying to integrate Paypal button to my website.
Paypal giving me this error after logging in for payment using sandbox credentials

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)

**I want track what is wrong in my request. Is there any way to get more details about errors?**

[image]

link to button page - [link](http://ibem.biz/paypal.php)

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox',
            client: {
                sandbox:    'AUI0tgjgg1Iipb0wwjDuXgmVpu2NG81xJvarBKhugpcpXhF8ECRzrUlNr_Dbpev0Rz5HKglbY5434Gkt',
                production: '<insert production client id>'
            },
            commit: true,
            payment: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }
        }, '#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please share how did you solved the issue?

Comment: @Pythonista This may be deprecated by now. Please look at the official documentation and examples from the PayPal GitHub repo. The code from there should work fine. Try asking chatgpt to save time

Answer (score 0):

Can you please a new sandbox business account, then use the newly created sandbox account for processing payments. Let us know if you still encounter the same issue with the new account also.

Comment: same issue with new one also